# Missing TxnLineID for LineGroup in SalesReceiptAdd

Tags: qbxml, qbwc

Working with examples I found I was able to add a SalesReceipt via QB WebConnector using QBXML.  Specifically I was adding a LineGroup (SalesReceiptLineGroupAdd) - and after adding that group I need to modify it.

Well to modify it I need the TxnLineID of the LineGroup.  It did not appear in my results - although the add and response were successes.  Roughly here is the outline of the request:

```
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="22">
            <SalesReceiptAdd>
                ... customer, billing, etc...
                <SalesReceiptLineGroupAdd>
                    <ItemGroupRef>
                        <FullName>2604-1</FullName>
                    </ItemGroupRef>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                </SalesReceiptLineGroupAdd>
            </SalesReceiptAdd>
        </SalesReceiptAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

And in the response:

```
<SalesReceiptLineGroupRet>
    <ItemGroupRef>
        <ListID>800002A9-1389300902</ListID>
        <FullName>2604-1</FullName>
    </ItemGroupRef>
    <Desc>test group 1</Desc>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    ... etc ...
```

but I expected

```
<SalesReceiptLineGroupRet>
    <TxnLineID>619-1394725756</TxnLineID>
    <ItemGroupRef>
        <ListID>800002A9-1389300902</ListID>
        <FullName>2604-1</FullName>
    </ItemGroupRef>
    <Desc>test group 1</Desc>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    ... etc ...
```

Based on the documentation.  What is wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that the examples you copied from are way out of date.  Switch to a newer version of qbmxl.  This worked for me:

`<?qbxml version="13.0"?>`

Comment: Is that work with 7.0 ? I use QuckBook 2013 primer version

Comment: Yes, <?qbxml version="3.0"?> and up support it, just not below.

Comment: 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 all working I had already tested, I had fixed groupline, By qbXML PaymentMethodRef not working in salesreceipt, even ClassRef working

Comment: Any clue why paymentMethodRef not working in salesreceipt

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the examples you copied from are way out of date.  Switch to a newer version of qmxl.  This worked for me:

```
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
```